# Отцентрировать ImageView по заданной точке

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, возможно ли для `ImageView` задать координаты определенной точки, по которой можно было бы отцентрировать `ImageView`?

Смысл в чём - есть картинка (линия), и я пытаюсь изменять ее положение по определенным событиям. Обычно в таком случае просто задаётся *х* и *у*, по которым перерисовывается изображение. Проблема в том, что относительно заданной точки изображение рисуется, условно говоря, вправо и вниз, т.е. эта точка является левым верхним углом изображения.

Возможно ли как-то задать отображение `ImageView` по точке, которая будет после отрисовки центром этой `ImageView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Элементарно. К примеру, Вы хотите поместить картинку `w*h` центром в точку `(xPos,yPos)`. Берете центральную точку и меняете на половину размера: `(xPos-w/2, yPos-h/2)`. Картинка перемещается по координатам `(xPos-w/2, yPos-h/2)`, центр ее в `(xPos,yPos)`.
Код:

```
int xPos = x; //х координата центра
int yPos = y; //у координата центра
xPos -= imageView.getWidth()/2;
yPos -= imageView.getHeight()/2;
//переместить картинку в (xPos, yPos);
```

Comment: Поделить на 2 где-то забыли...

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja точно, спасибо. Теорию расписал, а в примере ошибся :)

Comment: @VAndrJ Действительно элементарно. Чего это я... В любом случае, спасибо)